# Span a particular word in android

Tags: android

```
Hello All
```

In my android project i would like to display a particular word say TRIAL in string This is for my Trial.This Trial is just for fun.
How can achieve this in android.

I tried using below code which will format only the string from 15 to 30.

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01); 
Spannable WordtoSpan = new   SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know    just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");  
 WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 TV.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Please let me know if i could do this in android.

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don´t get what you´re trying to do

Comment: I would like to give the user a facility like if there is a lengthy text and he needs to find some text in that,the particular search text should be in red while rest in black :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the indexOf(String str) method in the String class. That'll give you the first occurence of the word you're searching for in your Spannable (which's an extended String). Then you can apply your Color-span accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Scythe's answer, replace them all with:

```
public class Junk extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String tvText = "This is for my Trial.This Trial is just for fun. Just a Trial";
        tvText+="A Trial. Only a Trial. It's a Trial"; 
        String lookFor = "Trial";
        tv.setText(formatString(tvText, lookFor));
    }

    private Spannable formatString(String targetStr, String lookFor) {

        Spannable spanString = null;
        spanString = new SpannableString(targetStr);
        int fromIndex, startSpan, endSpan;

        fromIndex = 0;
        while (fromIndex < (targetStr.length() - 1)) {
            startSpan = targetStr.indexOf(lookFor, fromIndex);
            if (startSpan == -1)
                break;
            endSpan = startSpan + lookFor.length();
            spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), startSpan,
                    endSpan, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            fromIndex = endSpan; 
        }
        return spanString;
    }
}
```

.

Comment: In this case, if you loop to `targetStr.length() - 1` you exclude last character.